How to upload pandas data frames fast with psycopg3?
I am trying to build a function which loads large chunks of a data frame into a PostgreSQL table. The chunking etc is not part of this question so I didn't included it in the minimal example. This question focuses only on the function copy_chunk or more precisely on how to use cur.copy. Inspired by this answer and the psycopg documentation I tried my luck with this function:
import pandas as pd
import psycopg
from io import StringIO

def copy_chunk(
    conn,  # noqa: ANN001
    df_chunk: pd.DataFrame,
    table_name: str,
) -> None:
    """Upload a single chunk to the database using the COPY command."""
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        # Create a buffer
        buffer = StringIO()
        df_chunk.to_csv(buffer, index=False, header=False)
        buffer.seek(0)

        # Load data into the table using copy method
        with cur.copy(f'COPY "{table_name}" FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV)') as copy:
            copy.write(buffer)
    conn.commit()

# Example usage
conn_string = "postgresql://username:password@hostname:port/dbname"
df_chunk = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 2, 3],
    'col2': ['A', 'B', 'C']
})

# Establish connection
with psycopg.connect(conn_string) as conn:
    copy_chunk(conn, df_chunk, 'your_table_name')


My current problem is that it doesn't throws any exception but also not filling up my table. Can you people spot my error?


Look at the Postgres log to see what is actually hitting the database. 2) Read COPY Block.  I think you need with buffer as f:  with cur.copy( ... 2) In the full code if you are creating the dataframe from some source you will probably find it more efficient to go straight from that source through psycopg copy.


The below worked for me. Note I used the psycopg sql module to dynamically create the SQL. This is safer in the long run:
import pandas as pd
import psycopg
from psycopg import sql
from io import StringIO

def copy_chunk(
    conn,  # noqa: ANN001
    df_chunk: pd.DataFrame,
    table_name: str,
) -> None:
    """Upload a single chunk to the database using the COPY command."""
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        # Create a buffer
        buffer = StringIO()
        df_chunk.to_csv(buffer, index=False, header=False)
        buffer.seek(0)
        
        copy_sql = sql.SQL('COPY {} FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV)').format(sql.Identifier(table_name))
        # Load data into the table using copy method
        with buffer as f:
            with cur.copy(copy_sql) as copy:
                 while data := f.read(10):
                    copy.write(data)

    conn.commit()

# Example usage
conn_string = "postgresql://postgres:@localhost:5432/test"
df_chunk = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 2, 3],
    'col2': ['A', 'B', 'C']
})

# Establish connection
with psycopg.connect(conn_string) as conn:
    copy_chunk(conn, df_chunk, 'pandas_test')

With the result being:
select * from pandas_test ;
 col1 | col2 
------+------
    1 | A
    2 | B
    3 | C
(3 rows)

Without the with buffer as f: I got this error:
object of type '_io.StringIO' has no len()
Using with buffer as f: iterates over the 'file' and sends the data to the COPY query.
